# SQLSRV Not Getting Data after PHP 5.6 Upgrade

Tags: php, iis, sqlsrv

I've got a problem that I can't seem to wrap my self around so the SO community seemed like the place to go!

I've got 3 PHP services that very simply return data from different tables of the same DB and spit it out as json. The 3 services all use the same exact code with a different select statement. The issue is that I'm able to get my data on two of the services but not on one (which happens to have the largest data set). I've matched my Resource Configuration from PHP 5.4 to 5.6 and still no results. All three services work fine on PHP 5.4 but after the 5.6 upgrade, only one doesn't (again, SAME CODE).

I'm attaching both services below so that you can compare. I've verified my SQL statements, and checked all log files. PHP shows no errors and IIS shows a 200 (completed GET on both services).

**FAILING SERVICE**

```
include "config/db.php";

$detailsConn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if (!$detailsConn)
{
    die('Connection failed!');
}

do
{

    $json = array();

    $detailsSql = "SELECT * from dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Desktop LEFT JOIN dbo.IPAddresses ON dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Desktop.IPAddressId=dbo.IPAddresses.IPAddressid WHERE IsDeleted = 'false'";
    $detailsStmt = sqlsrv_query($detailsConn, $detailsSql);

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($detailsStmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $json[] = $row;
    }

    $detailsSql = "SELECT * from dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Laptop LEFT JOIN dbo.IPAddresses ON dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Laptop.IPAddressId=dbo.IPAddresses.IPAddressid WHERE IsDeleted = 'false'";
    $detailsStmt = sqlsrv_query($detailsConn, $detailsSql);

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($detailsStmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
}

while (sqlsrv_next_result($detailsStmt));
echo json_encode($json);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($detailsStmt);
sqlsrv_close($detailsConn);
```

**WORKING SERVICE**

```
include "config/db.php";

$detailsConn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if (!$detailsConn)
{
    die('Connection failed!');
}

do
{
    $json = array();

    $detailsSql = "SELECT * from dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Yuma LEFT JOIN dbo.IPAddresses ON dbo.DeviceTypeTable_Yuma.IPAddressId=dbo.IPAddresses.IPAddressid WHERE IsDeleted = 'false'";
    $detailsStmt = sqlsrv_query($detailsConn, $detailsSql);

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($detailsStmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $json[] = $row;
    }

    $detailsSql = "SELECT * from dbo.DeviceTypeTable_iPad LEFT JOIN dbo.IPAddresses ON dbo.DeviceTypeTable_iPad.IPAddressId=dbo.IPAddresses.IPAddressid WHERE IsDeleted = 'false'";
    $detailsStmt = sqlsrv_query($detailsConn, $detailsSql);

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($detailsStmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
}

while (sqlsrv_next_result($detailsStmt));
echo json_encode($json);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($detailsStmt);
sqlsrv_close($detailsConn);
```

EDIT: I've reinstalled PHP 5.6 on the machine and made sure that my SQLSRV driver was properly installed(as it works on 2 others!).

I've also restarted IIS after all this to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my issue. Apparently there was data coming from a table that was not UTF-8 encoded therefore causing one service to fail. The solution to this was to drop `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"`into the array of connection details for SQLSRV. For some reason this encoding wasn't an issue on PHP 5.4 but from there on is. It is however in best practice to ensure that you're dropping that encoding in the database connection details.